# Targeting class that changes first part and still have the same last part

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey So I am making the game and I just need little help with making class dynamic if I can call it like that! So I have a variable of activePlayer and eventually, that activePlayer is going to change, there is two players princess and dog. So atm let activePlayer = dog; but next player after dog made the move will switch to princess.

So I tried to make  this   $(`.${activePlayer}_weapon`).html($this.data('image'));.html($this.data('image')), but seems that it wont work. So class is the dog_weapon and princess_weapon.

```
HTML: 
 <div class='player_1 mt-4'>
            <img src="./img/dog2.gif" style='width: 200px; height: 200px;'>
            <h2>Jake The Dog</h1>
            <h2>HP: <span id="dog_hp">100</span> </h2>
            <h3 class='dog_weapon'>Weapon:</h3>
            <h3>Attack: <span id="dog_attack">10</span></h3>

        </div>



 <div class='player_2 mt-4'>
        <img src="./img/princes2.gif" style='width: 200px; height: 200px;'>
            <h2>Lumpy Princess</h1>
            <h2>HP: <span id="princess_hp">100</span> </h2>
            <h3 class='princess_weapon'>Weapon:</h3>
            <h3>Attack: <span id="princess_attack">10</span></h3>


        </div>

        </div>



  if($this.hasClass('weapon')){
    console.log('Hey you are working');
    activePlayer.weapon = $this.data('name');
    activePlayer.damage = $this.data('power');
    $(`.${activePlayer}_weapon`).html($this.data('image'));



   };


}
```

I want it to $(`.${activePlayer}_weapon`).html($this.data('image')); change players when activePlayer changes to dog .${activePlayer} is dog and vice versa!

Comment: Can you show some html part ?

Comment: @ZweiJames Did it!

Comment: `activePlayer` is an object.

Comment: @Hikarunomemory yes it is and activePlayer in this situation is just dog. I just need to somehow swith them when activePlayer Changes!